# Karma webpack Error: no such file or directory /_karma_webpack_/

Tags: webpack, karma-runner, karma-webpack

I am using script

```
// src/test-index.js
const context = require.context('./src', true, /-test\.js$/)
context.keys().forEach(context)
```

And I keep running into error

```
> NODE_ENV=test karma start --single-run --no-auto-watch
...
ERROR [karma]: { Error: no such file or directory
    at MemoryFileSystem.readFileSync (PROJECT_ROOT/node_modules/memory-fs/lib/MemoryFileSystem.js:107:10)
    at MemoryFileSystem.readFile (PROJECT_ROOT/node_modules/memory-fs/lib/MemoryFileSystem.js:297:21)
    at doRead (PROJECT_ROOT/node_modules/karma-webpack/index.js:156:26)
    at Plugin.readFile (PROJECT_ROOT/node_modules/karma-webpack/index.js:160:3)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 34,
  message: 'no such file or directory',
  path: '/_karma_webpack_/test-index.js' }
Error: no such file or directory
    at MemoryFileSystem.readFileSync (PROJECT_ROOT/node_modules/memory-fs/lib/MemoryFileSystem.js:107:10)
    at MemoryFileSystem.readFile (PROJECT_ROOT/node_modules/memory-fs/lib/MemoryFileSystem.js:297:21)
    at doRead (PROJECT_ROOT/node_modules/karma-webpack/index.js:156:26)
    at Plugin.readFile (PROJECT_ROOT/node_modules/karma-webpack/index.js:160:3)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Here is link to [gist](https://gist.github.com/markogresak/ebfb1155347aa0959a008859c22e79a9/4c7c1c085ea7110fdabc0677be6eec053c980111) with my `karma.conf.js` and `webpack.config.js`. I've left other files out since these (plus the `test-index.js` above) are the only files involved in current process.

Node v6.2.0, npm v3.8.9 (installed via nvm). All dependencies were installed in last few hours so I am using latest versions.

Any ideas about what could be wrong or what else could I try?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with trying to reuse my original config for karma `webpack` config key.

I've solved the issue by changing karma config to:

```
webpack: {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel'
      }
    ]
  },
  externals: {
    cheerio: 'window',
    'react/addons': true,
    'react/lib/ExecutionEnvironment': true,
    'react/lib/ReactContext': true
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty'
  }
},
```

What's important here is `module` object and `node` object (to prevent *Cannot find module "fs"* errors). 
The `externals` part is specific to [enzyme](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/) and is was copied from their [Enzyme + Karma + Webpack guide](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/guides/karma.md#enzyme--karma--webpack). Also specific to how enzyme is working, note that there is no explicit `resolve` declaration since webpack automatically adds `'.js'` and `'.json'`, since enzyme is internally requiring both files. An alternative would be to explicitly declare json loader.